# No results to select sum to another table with OLEDB in VB.NET

Tags: sql, select, datagridview, oledb, dbf

Dear All Master,

I have tried but there is no result from sql select sum and only appears group from the column "PNM". Is there anything wrong with the sql I created?. is there any other solution?.
I don't know why it doesn't appear in the sum value in the "BLC" column in the TEMPTABL table.

Thanks

[image: view datagridview not result sql select sum]

[image: The sum result does not match]

```
 Private Sub fillDataGridView1()
        Try
            Dim query As String = "SELECT PNM,NOD,QTY,CIU,DPR FROM GSDTS WHERE QTY > 0"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        da.Fill(dt)
                        da.Dispose()
                        source1.DataSource = dt
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = source1
                        Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub fillDataGridView2()
        Try
            Dim query As String = "select * FROM TEMPTABL"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        da.Fill(dt)
                        da.Dispose()
                        source2.DataSource = dt
                        Me.DataGridView2.DataSource = source2
                        Me.DataGridView2.Refresh()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
  Sub deltemptabl()
        Try
            Dim sql As String = "DROP TABLE TEMPTABL"
            Using conn As New OleDbConnection(cn),
                       cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Catch myerror As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub temptablsum()
        Try
'here is the line of code below sql select sum

            Dim sql As String = "select PNM, sum((qty*ciu)*(1-dpr/100)) AS BLC INTO TEMPTABL from GSDTS group by PNM"
            Using conn As New OleDbConnection(cn),
                   cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Catch myerror As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

DPR is null, therefore it will return null when you try to compute it. You can account for that with isnull(), setting it to 1 (or whatever fits the scenario) whenever the column could be null

```
sum((qty*ciu)*(1-ISNULL(dpr,1)/100))
```

Edit:

After looking over it again, you may want to apply the isnull function to the entire sum to return 0 if null. It's difficult to give exacts as I dont know what each column means or specifics to the scenario

```
ISNULL(sum((qty*ciu)*(1-dpr/100)),0)
```

Edit/option 2:

Encapsulate that column in a case statement to handle the scenario if needed.

```
CASE WHEN DPR IS NOT NULL THEN sum((qty*ciu)*(1-dpr/100)) ELSE ReturnSomethingElse END AS DPR
```

Option 3:

Change the table column and front end to not accept null values if it's not viable for the scenario

Comment: Thank you for your reply. your answer first `sum((qty*ciu)*(1-ISNULL(dpr,1)/100))` but less bracket but the sum result is not appropriate. You can see the screenshot I attached . should be number 1000 with sum value result 200000 and number 1002 with sum value result 240000

Comment: The point is that NULL / 100 = NULL. I dont know your scenario or how you want to handle it when there is a null, I can only give you options.